# Filter transformation - null conditional

Tags: validation, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How does Informatica developer handle a null returned from a condition in a filter condition? Informatica treats it as if it were a true or a false?

Example in Filter condition:

```
IFF(size<52, TRUE, NULL)
```

Hypothetical example: I have a list of clothes with a size column, I want to filter sizes greater than 52, what would happen if the size is 50?

PD: I cannot modify the condition, it is already done by someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/transformation-language-reference/constants/null/null-values-in-filter-conditions.html):

> **If a filter condition evaluates to NULL, the function does not select the record.** If the filter condition evaluates to NULL for all records in the selected port, the aggregate function returns NULL (except COUNT, which returns 0). You can use filter conditions with aggregate functions and the CUME, MOVINGAVG, and MOVINGSUM functions.